# Ramanujan Pi formula and idoneal numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, ramanujan

The following question arises when I went through an [old table](https://archive.org/stream/lehrbuchderalgeb03webeuoft#page/720/mode/2up) of Heinrich Martin Weber.

1. It is obvious that Weber was trying to calculate class invariants related to idoneal numbers, where the numbers $n = 6, 10, 18, 22, 58$ and $n = 5, 9, 13, 25, 37$ had been used by Ramanujan for his hypergeometric series for $1/\pi$ published in [1914](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.pdf)(formula (35)-(44)). One can notice that the class invariants $2k/{k^\prime}^2$ or $2kk^\prime$ ($k^2+{k^\prime}^2=1 ,k=\theta_4^2(q)/\theta_3^2(q),q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}$) are fundamental units in some quadratic fields when we consider those numbers $n$ above.
2. The class invariants of certain numbers $n$(e.g. $n=190,253$) are fundamental units in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$ when considers $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ with class number 4. I am trying to figure out similar formulas of $1/\pi$ like those derived by Ramanujan:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(2\sqrt{n}v(k)m+G_0)\frac{(4m)!}{4^{4m}(m!)^4}c^m(k)$$

where $v(k),c(k)$ are rational functions of class invariants $2k/{k^\prime}^2$($n$ even) or $2kk^\prime$($n$ odd).

According to Borwein brothers,

$$G_0=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}\left(1-\frac{3}{2(((k^{\prime})^2/(2k))^2+1)}-\frac{1}{1+k^2}\frac{G_1}{2}\right)$$

$$G_1=\frac{nP(q^n)-P(q)}{(2K(k)/\pi)^2}$$

$$P(q) = 1 - 24\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\frac{jq^{2j}}{1 - q^{2j}}$$

$$q=e^{-\pi/\sqrt{n}}$$

if $n$ is even. One should replace $2k/{k^\prime}^2$ by $2kk^\prime$ if $n$ is odd.

3. $G_0$ should be algebraic numbers for $n>1,n\in \mathbb{Z}$. I tried to use PSLQ to find out the exact value of $G_0$ for idoneal numbers related to class number 4 quadratic fields. It is amazing that when the class invariant is a fundamental unit, then the number $G_0$ has a very simple form. Two examples are listed below:

$$G_0=\frac{1}{466578\sqrt{19}}(1877581-869892\sqrt{2})$$ for $n=190,$

$$G_0=\frac{1}{6523272}(-37515813+11937508\sqrt{11})$$ for $n=253.$(where $\vert G_0-1/\pi\vert\approx10^{-19}$)

**Question:** Is there an unified approach that why the forms of $G_0$ are very simple when $n$ are idoneal numbers(related to quadratic field with class number 2(or 4)) if the corresponding class invariants are fundamental units in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$, although modular equations are extremely complicated when $n$ is large?